# Change buffers in FakeVim

Tags: vim, qt-creator, fakevim

Does anyone know some shortcuts for [`FakeVim`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-editor-fakevim.html) to change between files?
Is it possible to use buffers in Fake `Vim`? I accidentally found out that `Ctrl+w,w` gets you the next window. Does anyone know other? For example getting to the left, right, top, bottom windows?(vim's `Ctrl+w,l` and others)? Is there any documentation on `FakeVim`? Is it possible to configure `FakeVim`'s vimrc file to create shortcuts for changing between buffers and the `Projects` view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I've been doing most of the changes on FakeVim plugin.

You can find list of Vim commands supported by FakeVim at https://github.com/hluk/FakeVim (recent version from Git master branch).

I'm still not sure how to document the features in Qt Creator. I'll probably implement something like `:help <command>` in near future.

Comment: waw, that's an impressive list.

Comment: Which doesn't contain windows/buffers movements.

Comment: Window/split operations are somehow incomplete and it depends on support in Qt Creator.I'll update the list after I've revised the current commands for moving in windows (`<C-W><LEFT>` works but `<C-W>h` doesn't; `:only` doesn't work correctly and it's hard to implement in Qt Creator).

Answer (score 1):

[The FakeVim documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.5/creator-editor-fakevim.html) is severely lacking. This paragraph, for example, is so fuzzy it's borderline irresponsible:

> In the FakeVim mode, most keystrokes in the main editor will be intercepted and interpreted in a way that resembles Vim. Documentation for Vim is not included in Qt Creator. For more information on using Vim, see Documentation on the Vim web site.

Basically, without a proper documentation or a look at the editor's source code it's impossible to know what should work, what shouldn't and in which way the behavior of what works deviates from Vim's behavior. And that's what passes for a modern IDE, these days.

Whatever…

I think that your best bet is simply trial and error: since you appear to know how to use Vim you'll have a lot of commands and shortcuts to try.

Comment: It's sad that this doesn't reflect the so well written Qt documentation we've been used with... :(